# Scanf in struct containing 'double' array doesnt work?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I have to program a scalarproduct ((x1*y1)+(x2*y2)) with the use of structs and scanf. 
However my program just skips y1 and counts both y1 and x2 as the same number even though I type in completely different numbers??
I did the following:

```
 struct _point2d
    {
       double x[1];  // this means x1 is x[0] and x2 is x[1]
       double y[1];
    };

double PscalarProduct( double a, double b, double c, double d )
{
    printf("The scalar product ((x1*y1) + (x2*y2)) (whereas x1 = %lf, 
y1 = %lf, x2 = %lf, y2 = %lf) is %lf\n", a, b, c, d, (( a*b ) + ( c*d )) );
    }


int main()
{   
    struct _point2d Vector;
    Vector.x[1];
    Vector.y[1];

printf("Enter x1 and y1 \n"); 
    scanf("%lf", &(Vector.x[0]));
    scanf("%lf", &(Vector.y[0]));
printf("Enter x2 and y2 \n");
    scanf("%lf", &(Vector.x[1]));
    scanf("%lf", &(Vector.y[1]));
PscalarProduct(Vector.x[0], Vector.y[0], Vector.x[1], Vector.y[1]);


 return 0;
    }
```

However if i run the program with the numbers 1[=x1] 2[=y1] 3[=x2] 4[=y2] I receive this text:

```
The scalar product ((x1*y1) + (x2*y2)) (whereas x1 = 1.000000, y1 = 3.000000, x2 = 3.000000, y2 = 4.000000) is 15.000000
```

How can this be that y1 and x2 are the same numbers??? y1 should be the number 2.00000.

Comment: When having trouble with `scqnf()`, the first step is to amend code to check the return value.  `if (scanf("%lf", &(Vector.x[0])) != 1) Handle_Error();`

Comment: In this case thought, maybe `Vector.x[1];` --> `Vector.x[2];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct members `x` and `y` arrays can hold only one element each. But you are reading 2 elements as input.

In C, array index ranges from `0` to `N-1`. Your code has *undefined behaviour* due to out of bounds access.

Increase the array size:

```
 struct _point2d
    {
       double x[2]
       double y[2];
    };
```